# Unable to Select & Print of month in a Calendar in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, calendar

As I am new to Selenium Automation . I am trying my hands on Calendar . My code work correctly for selecting Year & Month but it didn't work when I tried printing & selecting Month on right side of table . When we click on calendar on booking.com website then two months appear simultaneously . One on Left side & another on Right side . It was Printing the month value correctly & is able to select the month correctly until code is able to shift the value of month on Left side .. When I selected the November 2022 . Which is the last month shown in the list & this month appear on Right side . Here my code is unable to print & select the value for November but for another months it's printing fine ... Please guide me how can I select & print the value of month that appear on right side of calendar table ... Thank U in advance.... Below I am sharing my code details :-

```
**
package HandlingCalendars;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BookingDotCom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String bookingdate = "21-November-2022";
        String[] temp = bookingdate.split("-");
        String date = temp[0];
        String month = temp[1];
        String year = temp[2];
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-mode,'checkin')]")).click();
        
        String yearmonth = driver.findElement(By.className("bui-calendar__month")).getText();
        String[] G = yearmonth.split(" ");
        String newmonth = G[0];
        String newyear = G[1];
        
        while(!newyear.equals(year)){
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bui-calendar__control bui-calendar__control--next']")).click();
            yearmonth = driver.findElement(By.className("bui-calendar__month")).getText();
            G = yearmonth.split(" ");
            newmonth = G[0];
            newyear = G[1];
        }
        
        
        
        while(!newmonth.equalsIgnoreCase(month)){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bui-calendar__control bui-calendar__control--next']")).click();
            yearmonth = driver.findElement(By.className("bui-calendar__month")).getText();
            G = yearmonth.split(" ");
            newmonth = G[0];
            newyear = G[1];
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(newmonth);
        
    }

}

**
```

Comment: Not answering your question, use `LocalDate` for a date and `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing your string into a `LocalDate`. See [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things to be noted :

1. Use right locators.
2. Use Explicit waits when dealing with dynamic content.

**Sample code :**

```
@Test
public void testSO() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

String bookingdate = "21-November-2022";
String[] temp = bookingdate.split("-");
String date = temp[0];
String month = temp[1];
String year = temp[2];

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-mode,'checkin')]"))).click();

String leftMonth_WithYear = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("bui-calendar__month"))).getText();
String[] G = leftMonth_WithYear.split(" ");
String leftNewMonth = G[0];
String leftNewYear = G[1];

while(true){
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='bui-calendar__month'])[2]")).getText().split("\\ ")[0].equals(month) && driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='bui-calendar__month'])[2]")).getText().split("\\ ")[1].equals(year)) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@data-bui-ref, 'calendar-next')]//*[name()='svg']"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}

System.out.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//div[@class='bui-calendar__month'])[2]"))).getText());
```

}

**Output :**

> November 2022

Comment: HI Thank u for taking time & replying me  ! I have one question : -      ```````````````````````````````````` `````````````````````````````````````````````  String leftMonth_WithYear = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("bui-calendar__month"))).getText();
String[] G = leftMonth_WithYear.split(" ");
String leftNewMonth = G[0];
String leftNewYear = G[1];    ```````````````````````````````````````````````  What is the use of this in code ?? Bcz we are not using right ??`

Comment: Yes that is not required, when I editing your code, I just updated that part. Feel free to remove those line.

Comment: Done Done ! Thank U Soooooooooooooooooo Much ......Love U ...

Comment: I think it will take some more days to understand all these things ... If you don't mind please tell me how much time will it take to learn & what's the better way to practice .. Thank U

Comment: Bro, I think you are missing this. Please read `You can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –`

Comment: Yes thanks, only practice is a way to learn selenium. You can try for like 2 hours every day for a month, and you will gain sufficient knowledge to proceed further without any help from anyone.

Comment: I am sitting since morning .. But I am really facing issue with Calender's ... Of different websites ... Where I am getting confuse is .. Before this code : I thought I have practice good in Xpath .. But when I checked yours .. how you created a Xpath with [2] ... Then it stuck my mind .. Ohhh ! I am still lagging .... I need more practice on Xpath also ... Along with other concept ... HHahahahaa....

Answer (score 1):

Below line points to 2 elements in the DOM - `October 2022` and `November 2022`.

```
yearmonth = driver.findElement(By.className("bui-calendar__month")).getText();
```

So by default it selects the first option `October 2022`.

Use this `xpath` instead of `class_name` to get the text of `month` on the right side.

```
//div[@class='bui-calendar__wrapper'][2]/div
```

Or change

```
yearmonth = driver.findElement(By.className("bui-calendar__month")).getText();
```

to

```
months = driver.findElements(By.className("bui-calendar__month"));
yearmonth = months[1].getText();
```