# Automate date-picker based on month text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am trying to automate date-picker on a page, and I want to hit the previous/next button until I reach a desired month in the calendar. But the button does not click, only once it clicks and test cases passes without going any further. Current month is September it clicks and goes to August and the test case passes without being clicked further, lets say if I wish to click till January it does not happen

```
@FindBy(css=".ui-datepicker-month") //month displayed in date-picker
WebElement labelCalendarMonth;

@FindBy(id="txtStartDate_calendarButton") // button to open the date-picker
WebElement searchStartDateButton;

@FindBy(xpath="//a[@title='Prev']") // previous button in date-picker
WebElement calendarSearchStartDatePreviousBtn;

public void selectStartMonth(WebElement ele, String value) {
  if(!labelCalendarMonth.getText().equals(value))
  {
    ele.click();
  }
}

public void clickCalendarSearchStartDatePreviousBtn() throws InterruptedException
{
    selectStartMonth(calendarSearchStartDatePreviousBtn, "January");
}

@Test()
public void testAddResourceSchedule() throws InterruptedException 
{
    resourceSchedulePage.clickCalendarSearchStartDatePreviousBtn();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with `https://www.booking.com/` and they do have date picker, so just to give you little head up how do we handle this situation where we have to click till certain amount of time, for e.g: till Jan in your case, we can do the following :-

It's kind of obvious that we have to have `infinite while loop.`

```
while(true){
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("month xpath which you wanna selct ")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(month) && driver.findElement(By.xpath("year xpath that you wanna select")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(year)) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("next botton xpath here, which is on date picker."))).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Basically, the thing is you need to define `month` and `year` in advance in a `string format.` before running this code.

I have written a good solution here [as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949095/unable-to-select-print-of-month-in-a-calendar-in-selenium/68950461#68950461) where I am clicking till end of `Nov-2022`

Comment: `wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`, you need to declare this as well before executing this while loop.

Comment: This is clicking fine, not stopping one just one click as it was doing earlier, but it is clicking infinite times even though I mentioned the year and month, so I'm trying to figure that out, but thanks a ton, I'm moving further because of this.

Comment: this loop will only break the infinite loop if and only if, if condition is met, so you better check what we have inside if braces.

Comment: Your solutions works fine, but I feel we should have ```driver.findElement(By.xpath("month xpath which you wanna selct ")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(month)``` as I was entering month in capitalized case but in calendar it is in capital case, but anyways the solutions works brilliantly.